arma::mat division by const integer causes problems
I have a function I call from R using Rcpp. I pass an argument, which is a const unsigned integer, to this function. The integer is used to scale a matrix consisting of random draws. MWE:
Rcpp::cppFunction('

auto testfun(const arma::uword n = 10)
{  
  arma::dmat W = floor(arma::randu(35, 35, arma::distr_param(0, 2)));
  return W / n;
}
', depends = "RcppArmadillo", plugins = "cpp17")

This MWE makes my R crash. My actual code, on the other hand, works but returns garbage. What am I missing here?
It appears that the auto declaration is causing the problems. I don't understand why.

Have a look at Extending R with C++: A Brief Introduction to Rcpp, a vignette that came with Rcpp and is also a paper. The signature auto f(arma::uword n) violates two key assumptions of what compiled functions extending R have to look like so it is maybe not entirely surprising things go sideways.  Maybe start over from RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(), look at the sample functions it includes and build up from there.  And with reasonably recent R the C++17 is actually the default (with a suitable compiler).

thanks for your reply. If I understand your point correctly, you are saying that the above code would be fine in normal C++ but only fail in Rcpp due to its nature?

Using the documented interfaces and types for which RcppArmadillo contains the templated converters turns your failing function into a working function.
(Here I also scale the dims from 35 to 5 for more compact display. It works either way. I also add two linebreaks for the display here. )
> Rcpp::cppFunction("arma::mat f(const int n = 10) { 
          arma::mat W = floor(arma::randu(5,5,arma::distr_param(0,2))); 
          return W / n; }", depends="RcppArmadillo") 
> f() 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.0
[2,]  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.0
[3,]  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.0
[4,]  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.0
[5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1
> f(2) 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0
[2,]  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.5
[3,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0
[4,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0
[5,]  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.5
>  

